# Bootstrap 5 Navbar doesn't collapse on phone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

hello can you check this I cannot see the navbar when I turn to the phone please I need some help I want to finish it today, hope someone solve it for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="photo/LOGO.png" alt="logo"></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
       target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
       aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link " href="index.html"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Home</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="oO.html"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">OO</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">RR</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="NN.html"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">NN</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="CC.html"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">CC</button></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
              <form class="d-flex" >
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark me-3" type="submit" href="#"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark me-3" type="submit" href="#"><i class="bi bi-discord"></i></button>
              </form>
            </div>
        </nav> 
    
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img src="photo/dragonoid rr.jpg"  class="img-fluid" alt="rr" style="width: 1000px;  " >
        </div>
    
        <script src="/js/all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: try with a different `id` for the navbar, I just tried adding a 1 at the end and it worked

Comment: Hi! I notice that you are using alt="rr" - it's good that you have an alt attribute but this text is not going to be helpful to assistive technologies that infer meaning from your markup. If the image is Dragonoid you likely just need to change this to alt="Dragonoid". You can learn more about alt text here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decision-tree/#:~:text=This%20decision%20tree%20describes%20how,instead%20of%20images%20of%20text.